# Server randomly hangs, with the only way out a forced reboot

Tags: server, remote-desktop, vnc, 19.10, xserver

For whatever reason, having an X server installed causes my headless server to completely hang (no response to any pings, attempts to ssh in, input on exsiting ssh connections, anything. waiting 10+ minutes doesn't un-hang the server), with the only solution being to force a reboot via my hosters web interface. **EDIT**: confirmed X server probably is actually not causing it. Removing xserver-xorg didn't help.

Looking around online, I saw some complaints about linux kernel 5.3 with Xorg/X server causing hangs.

Because I need a server that doesn't crash every 30-45 min with absolutely no trace in logs of why, I chose to remove xorg and all of the related compenents.

After fighting with VNC and no X server for about 30min, the server hung again. What could be the problem?

Syslog from last crash: https://pastebin.com/1X3Zryd4

It's a server running on an AMD Ryzen 5 3600, with 64GB DDR4 RAM and two 512GB NVMe SSDs in RAID 0. Running Ubuntu 19.10

*Edit: Interestingly enough removing all packages related to X11, GNOME, and XFCE seems to have gotten rid of the problem. Service called NetworkManager was requesting a suspend, according to the logs at the link. Now the question is why?*

Comment: You could look at the last log messages before the crash with `journalctl -b -1 -e`

Comment: This may seem a little odd, but a preliminary look at the log files you posted indicates that the system is not crashed, but suspended.  It received a command to go to sleep at Nov 22 15:43:36, and entered a suspended state within a second.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I did actually notice that, which would explain why ssh became inaccessible. Not sure why NetworkManager would request a suspend though

Comment: @CharlesGreen updated the question

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that NetworkManager is requesting the suspend operation - that's a little beyond my paygrade.  I would suspect that the the use USER_AVC (uid 103) is a raphical user, that has been set to suspend automatically after a certain period of time.  in `dconf`, this might be in the section `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power`, but it may be in alternate settings also.

Comment: @CharlesGreen after removing Gnome that was what was showing up on logs but yeah probably gotta take a look at power settings

Comment: @CharlesGreen removing everything relayed to Xfce seems to have solved it. Lxde doesn't seem to have that setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was XFCE's built in power management. It was suspending the server after 30 minutes, rendering it inaccessible

Switched to LXDE and no further problems

Also need to forcibly disable hibernate and sleep services:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

(Source: https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend)

Comment: I'm glad to hear this worked out for you.  I would assume that somewhere in XFCE there is a way to change that setting...

Comment: @CharlesGreen ironically lxde demonstrates same issue but now I know what it was at least and nuked and power management services